# Computer analysis of authorship in Daniel?

Tags: translation-philosophy, hermeneutical-approaches, daniel

Computers have demonstrated that Genesis was probably written by one person
https://www.nytimes.com/1981/11/08/world/computer-points-to-single-author-for-genesis.html

I've been looking around and can't find that anyone has run a similar analysis of Daniel. Has anyone done this? It would be interesting to see whether a computer analysis backs up the claims that Daniel had three or four authors.

Comment: maybe the same professor will do it for Daniel. Though it sounds like an "easy" program to run. The multiple-author idea for Genesis was always absurd on its face

Comment: You make it seem as if a computer is unbiased.  The program art builds in his assumptions in a biased way that unlikely to be transparent.

Comment: The team said usage and frequency provided ''a reliable gauge of authorship'' because they were stylistic nuances ''beyond the author's conscious control.''

Comment: @WalterSmetana  That might work from week to week or year to year,  but I know that my writing style and vocabulary are very different now than 20 years ago.   Also  if I were compiling information from different written sources I might adopt some of the vocabulary of my sources.     Those differences would be apparent even if I was the writer.

Comment: Programming Big Blue to beat a Chess Master is one thing, but the human mind is vastly more capable of linguistic analysis (and that without much effort) than is a designed program. Our minds were created for language. There are depths within us that perceive and understand, layer upon layer, what language is and what language does.

Comment: Style and authorship are distinct notions. It would be best not to confuse them.

Comment: Related: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/468/can-we-use-linguistic-fingerprints-to-identify-different-authors-of-the-bible